# formData not changing with ngChange hook

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

I have a very basic scenario where in which I have a **module** with one **controller**:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myModuleCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {url:'',title:'',source:''};

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.formData.url = 'Test';
        $scope.formData.title = '';
        $scope.formData.source = '';
    };

    $scope.manageUrl = function() {
        alert('update');
    };
});
```

In my view I'm trying to hook the `formData` object properties to some form fields using `ngModel`. However my input doesn't update it's value after the `init()` method runs. If I add the `ngChange` directive and hook that up with the `$scope.manageUrl()` method, it only runs *once*, after my first keystroke/change of the input.

**Am I missing something here? I've used both directives before without any problems. Only thing I can think of is something wrong with my module/controller setup?**

This is what my **view** looks like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myModuleCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div>
        <form name="myForm">
            <div>
                <input type="url" ng-model="formData.url" ng-change="manageUrl()" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my **application.js bootstrapper**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running `$scope.init()` in your controller after you've defined it?

Comment: Yes `init()` runs, Shoms was right on the input type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the url validator, note how the whole url property is removed until you enter a valid url, that's when you'll start to get your alerts back. Basically, once removed, the url is never considered to be changed until a valid (and different) url is input.

- url is set to 'Test'
- you type anything into the box, it fails the validation and becomes undefined
- it stays undefined until you enter a valid url (it's not changing)

Start typing `http://anything` and see what happens yourself:

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myModuleCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {url:'',title:'',source:''};
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.formData.url = 'Test';
        $scope.formData.title = '';
        $scope.formData.source = '';
    };

    $scope.manageUrl = function() {
        alert('update');
    };
});

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myModuleCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div>
        <form name="myForm">
            <div>
                <input type="url" ng-model="formData.url" ng-change="manageUrl()" />
              
              <br>
              {{formData}}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> **Am I missing something here? I've used both directives before without any problems. Only thing I can think of is something wrong with my module/controller setup?**

The only logical solution that comes to my mind is that you've used a different input type before, so you were not a subject to validations. If you change the type to `text`, it works fine the whole time.

Comment: Fair enough, i didn't know that. Thanks!